# Very Basic Jquery - Why wont this if / else with a variable work?

Tags: jquery

The code in the if should only execute one time, but somehow, it works all the time

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;                       
    if(count = 0){
        $('#enter').click(function() {
            count = 1;
            $(this).fadeTo("fast","0.8");
        });
    } else {};
});
```

Comment: Just do this: `if(count === 0){ ` w/o any type conversion being done.

Comment: Do you mean that the click should only execute once? You've got your if in the wrong place - it's triggered when setting up the click handler, and after that it'll continue working until unregistered - which you aren't doing. You could move the count test inside the handler instead.

Comment: Not sure if you removed the content for the sake of the question, but if you don't have anything in the else block you don't need to use else at all.

Comment: Thanks rup! that was actually the problem, it actually overlooked the if! should have known this from the beginning

Comment: You don't need the counter at all if you use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `if(count == 0){` or `if(count === 0){`

You need to have `==` (*Equality operator*) or `===` (*Identity operator*).
Otherwise with `count = 0` you are saying/assigning that `count` should be `0`, instead of comparing them.

If you want to compare `type` also you can have `count === 0`, in some cases it can be good. For example `false == 0` returns `true`. But `false === 0` returns `false`.

You can read more about operators here: **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)**.

---

About the idea behind your `count` variable, you should review it. As it is the if will always go thru (even with the corrected `=`). Because you assign `zero` and on the next line pass the `if` with true. Maybe you want to have the `if` condition inside the `.click()` so it will return `true`/`false` depending on how you want.

Answer (score 3):

`if(count = 0)` is an assignment

Try this:-

```
if(count == 0)
```

**Note:-** `=` is for assignment and `==` is for logical comparison. By doing `count = 0`, Javascript thinks you are trying to assign a variable named `count` as 0.

Answer (score 0):

because you are assigning value to `count` every time in if statement.

Its not comparing.

Try:-

```
if(count == 0)
```

or you can also try

```
if(count === 0)
```

it will also look for the type match of count